# How might I fade + slide an element in?

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to slide + fade an element in, when I try doing

```
$("ul", this).fadeIn(300).slideDown(600);
```

I just get the fadeIn, how can I fade while slide an element in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use animation for this

```
$("ul").animate({
"height": "toggle", "opacity": "toggle" 
}, "slow");
```

Answer (score 2):

this will slide down then fade in

insert this function somewheres

```
jQuery.fn.doubleHide = function(){
    return $(this).hide().css('opacity', '0');
}


jQuery.fn.slideFade = function(slide, fade){
return $(this).slideDown(slide, function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(fade, 100);
    });
}
```

then u can call this function like the fadeIn()

```
        $(this).stop(true).doubleHide().slideFade(400, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling hide() on it first, either in chaining or otherwise, and swap the functions around, :

```
$("ul").hide().slideDown(600).fadeIn(300);
```

Comment: @TheDeveoper I'm afraid that still makes the calls in procedural order. fadeIn will not start until slideDown has completed.